# Serial number in PHP

Tags: php, auto-increment, serial-number

Please I am building a table in php that will list item from database, the amount listed depends on amount available. I want to number my **s/n** column serially using php.
eg.

```
s/n      Name       amount
1       Mathew     $12
2
3
4
etc
```

Comment: If you already have something, show us. If not, try yourself and ask if any errors come up and we'll help you with them.

Comment: take an additional counter variable and increment it in loop

Comment: This depends on how you extract and have your columns stored in PHP. Do you just fetch associative arrays or what? Show the code where you retrieve the rows from DB and we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Try MYSQL's auto increment. So the first user who registers gets SN 1 and second would get 2 etc

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

see [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
<?php
// array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Comment: I did not, But he needs a counter variable to be echoed and incremented in the loop OP have already

Comment: @shakti Singh  you got too much reputation within few days :) Congrats.

Comment: Downvoted because your example isn't relevant and won't work. If he already has a dataset coming from a database, `range` cannot help him. That is also the most inefficient way possible to loop over a range of numbers.

Comment: @diEcho: I wouldn't let 2 anonymous downvotes ruin your day. You've been on SO for nearly 2 years, you should realize its all just part of the game.